# Flutter Firestore Query List Using WhereIn

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection I am querying and referencing another document that I have already queried prior (`teamRecord`). In this case everything is working up to the final 'user_inchallenge' call. In this case, the `user_inchallenge` is a DocumentReference and the `teamRecord.usersInTeam` is a List of DocumentReferences. However, there `whereIn` call does not seem to be working properly. I only want to return docs where `user_inchallenge` is held within `teamRecord.usersInTeam`.

```
FirebaseFirestore
.instance
.collection('activity_units')
.orderBy('activity_value', descending: true)
.where('challenge_reference', isEqualTo: challenges.reference)
//below is not working
.where('user_inchallenge', whereIn: teamRecord.usersInTeam.asList())
```

As a note, if I remove the `.asList()` call in `usersInTeam` I get the error:

> The argument type 'BuiltList<DocumentReference>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

I also tried `isEqualTo`, `arrayContains`, but none of them have returns the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

The `whereIn` parameter expects a `List`, and it seems that `BuiltList` is not actually a `List`.

You'll want to convert your `BuiltList` to a `List` (e.g. by calling `asList()` or `toList()` on it) and then pass *that* to the Firestore call.

I filed [issue #10407](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10407) on the GitHub repo to see if the types can be change to be `Iterable`.

Comment: Thank you! I think that would be a good edit for the types.

Comment: No matter what changes you make, even if you transform the data into a static format like ['AAA', 'BBB'], it won't yield any results because "wherein" is not functioning. This new feature is still incomplete and has serious bugs.

Comment: @Kevin I've successfully used `whereIn` in multiple Flutter projects. If you're having a hard time making it work, I recommend posting a new question for it with your own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can check what's going on.